# Page Search Driven Content

Tags: search-results, page-layout

After creating a custom page layout based on the Article content type, page results no longer show up in search. What could be the issue here?

Comment: Is the page checked in and published and approved?

Comment: Yes it is, checked in and approved.. I tested this before, new pages created with the normal page layout article shows up in the search results even if it is not checked in.

Comment: Look in the crawl log for errors then

Comment: Hi Robert, thanks much, it was the page layout that was not approved !

Comment: Please remember to post that as an answer to help future readers, glad I could push you in the right direction at least :)

Answer (score -1):

The page layout was not checked in and published and approved. After doing this it appeared in the search results.